# Why are $\mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{m}^2+I)$ and $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$ canonically isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I were studying [this notes](http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/09-10/Spring/18.726/l_8.pdf) on Zariski cotangent space and in Lemma 8.3 I came across the statement that $\mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{m}^2+I)$ and $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$ are canonically isomorphic, where $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$ are maximal ideal in stalks of regular functions of the whole space and affine variety respectively. The point is fixed on variety and $I$ is and ideal generating our variety.

I do not see this isomorphism, but since the author states that it is canonical, I guess it follows from abstract algebra. Hence, consider following framework.

Let $S,T$ be two commutative unitial rings with an ring epimorphism $F:S\to T$ and put $I=\ker F.$ In addition assume that $J_S$ is an ideal in $S$ such that $I\subset J_S.$ Since $F$ is surjective we have that $J_T=F(J_S)$ is an ideal in $T.$

We easily see that $F$ induces surjective map from $J_S\to J_T$ and since $F(J_s)=J_T$ and $F(I)=0$ we get that $F(J_S^2+I)\subset J_T^2.$ As a result we induces the surjective map
$$\gamma:J_S/(J_S^2+I)\to J_T/J_T^2$$

> **Question** Is this map mono?
>
> ---

**Edit. (Reduction of the problem)** We can simplify the problem using first isomorphism thm. Let $\alpha:J_S\to J_T$ be restriction of $F$ to $J_S$ and let $\pi :J_T\to J_T/J_T^2$ be the cannocical projection. If we compute the $\ker(\pi\circ\alpha),$ then we could use first isomorphism thm then. So
$$\ker(\pi\circ\alpha)=\alpha^{-1}(J_T^2)=F^{-1}(J_T^2)\cap J_S.$$

> **Question. (Simpler)** Is $F^{-1}(J_T^2)=J_S^2+I$ for such $F$ and $J_S$ as abowe?

Notice that if that would be the case, then 
$$\ker(\pi\circ\alpha)=F^{-1}(J_T^2)\cap J_S=(J_S^2+I)+J_S=J_S^2+I.$$

Comment: I think is the second isomorphism theorem for modules.

Comment: If $I \subseteq J$ are ideals of a ring $A$, then we have an equality $(J/I)^{2} = (J^{2}+I)/I$ of ideals of the quotient ring $A/I$.

Comment: @MinseonShin I do not see how to use this fact. Am I restricted $F$ to $\alpha$ too quickly? I realy wish you could expand your comment in form of an answer with some additional steps.

Comment: Just a comment, recall that there are epimorphisms of rings that are not surjections, for example any localization map $A \to S^{-1}A$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings.

Comment: @MinseonShin I find out that recenty, but I was not familiar with this example. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in the title: In the setup of the notes you linked to, we have $A := k[x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n}]$ and $I$ is an ideal of $A$ contained in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = \langle x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n} \rangle \subset A$. Let $\mathfrak{n} := \mathfrak{m}/I$ be the corresponding maximal ideal of $A/I$. Then we have $\mathfrak{n}^{2} = (\mathfrak{m}/I)^{2} = (\mathfrak{m}^{2}+I)/I$, hence $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^{2} = (\mathfrak{m}/I)/((\mathfrak{m}^{2}+I)/I) = \mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{m}^{2}+I)$.

Comment: Almost perfect. Sorry, but I still do not see why $(J/I)^{2} = (J^{2}+I)/I$ in $A/I$ for any ideals $I \subseteq J.$ From the definition of multiplication in $A/I$ we have that $(J/I)^2$ is just a notation of $J^2/I$ in $A/I$ (am I right here?). So this means that $J^2/I=(J^{2}+I)/I,$ but in this I doubt.

Comment: Note that $J^{2}$ may not contain $I$ so "$J^{2}/I$" may not make sense, for example in case $A = k[x]$ and $J = I = (x)$. By definition, $(J/I)^{2}$ is the ideal of $A/I$ generated by elements of the form $(x_{1}+I)(x_{2}+I) = x_{1}x_{2}+I$ for $x_{1},x_{2} \in J$, and one can check by hand that this is equal to $(J^{2}+I)/I$.